# getting image from my server when my website has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html page with 1000 images and it's very slow to load in my browser.

I want to load the images using the scroll effect like this example :

Like the web site http://www.jumia.ma/catalog/?q=iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Lazy Load plugin for that: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

This plugin delays loading of images from server until they appear in users viewport. So after you load the page, script check that images are visible and loads them. When you scroll, it automatically checks if new images appear and loads them as well. You can also configure any additional effects, etc.

Comment: This plugins delays loading of images from server until they appear in users viewport. So after you load the page, script check that images are visible and loads them. When you scroll, it automatically checks if new images appear and loads them as well. You can also configure any additional effects, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That's something that you can include in your answer to improve it -- I've already done that for you :)